# Copy in Postgres from a tab delimited file to table

Tags: postgresql, copy, csv

I am working on a copy command to copy the contents of a tab delimited file with a header to a table in postgres. I have used copy before so I know how it works but I have a question regarding how I can get around some data being missing in the file.

I have premade the table to have the same column names as the values in the header.

Some of the "columns" from the file that I received are just blank. I have put fake data in just to get the command working but this is something that is going to be automated weekly. I was wondering if I am just going to have to tell the people to make sure their data is correct or if there is a way to tell the copy command to input a NULL in the place of blank data.

I thought I might have to place in blank tabs and that would act as a null but I wasn't sure if that was the best course of action.

Comment: The usual approach is to have a staging table that is "dumb" and does not "validation" at all (e.g. no constraints, all columns as `text`). Then use `insert into .. select .. ` to copy the "valid" rows from the staging table to the real table.

Comment: That's the kind of approach that I am taking now except that I manually added in the word "NULL" into the fields that had no data whatsoever. I would like to try to get this to become automated by the copy command somehow but I am not sure how or if that is even possible.

Comment: The file is thousands of rows long is the problem so filling in all of that missing data with a "NULL" by hand is just impractical.

Comment: So it looks like just having blank tabs where the data is empty is going to be the way to go, I will just have to let the person creating the file know this so I don't have to manually add them in myself.

Comment: What if you use  `NULL AS ''` (an empty string)?

Comment: Hmmm so that means that anything that isnt a TAB and is just an empty string (space) will be flagged as null? I will try this out as soon as possible and see if that works. The only issue that I can see happening is some of this missing data might have multiple spaces in between the tabs from what I can see. It's looking more and more like the people who made this file originally hand typed or copy and pasted this out and made many mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

[Documentation for `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) specifies, that default value for `NULL`s is `\N`. So changing it to be empty as @a_horse_with_no_name suggest is the way to go.

Another way is to preprocess the file using any other tools. I quite often do the following in my scripts:

```sql
psql dbname <<EOSQL
COPY tab FROM stdin WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL 'NULL');
$(printf "1\t2\t3\n4\t\t6\n7\t8\t\n\t10\t11\n"| \
  sed -e 's/\(\t\|^\)\(\t\|$\)/\1NULL\2/g')
\.
EOSQL
```

Instead of `printf` you can cat your file. Use whatever manipulations required.
*Note: I'm on OSX, so `sed` syntax may vary for you.*

Also, in the current PostgreSQL CommitFest there's [a patch](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/action/patch_view?id=985) to add generic Pre- and Post- processors to the `COPY` command. [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/002101cd9190%24081c4140%241854c3c0%24@lab.ntt.co.jp) you can find the whole discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I am going to try what a_horse_with_no_name suggested and see if that will work out for me. and yes I did think about doing some processing before the copying I just wanted to see if there was a simpler way before I dove into that.Thank you!